# sqldf avg of n columns grouped

Tags: r, sqldf

Id like to get grouped averages of n (many) columns applying a sql-query on an R data frame. 
How it works for a single column is below. However, Id like to execute the statement on for example all columns without explicitly stating them.

what I've tried is for example:

```
sqldf('SELECT some_ID, other_ID, AVG(colnames(data_frame_name) FROM data_frame_name GROUP BY some_ID, other_ID') 

sqldf('SELECT some_ID, other_ID, AVG(column_name) FROM data_frame_name GROUP BY some_ID, other_ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible to solve it with pure SQL, and `sqldf` can help if SQL can solve.

But R has many other tools, like `dplyr` from `tidyverse`.
Code below do the job. You put your some_ID, other_ID to 'group_by' and have mean of all numeric columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_all( mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin `anscombe` dataset we add an `id` column
and then produce the selection clause, `sel`, in the next two lines.
Finally we run `sqldf`.  Add the `verbose=TRUE` argument to `sqldf` if you
want to see the final SQL statement displayed.

```
library(sqldf)

anscombe$id <- rep(1:2, c(5, 6)) # test data

Names <- setdiff(names(anscombe), "id")  # names excluding id
sel <- toString(sprintf("avg(%s) as %s", Names, Names))
fn$sqldf("select id, $sel from anscombe group by id")
```

giving:

```
  id   x1   x2   x3       x4       y1   y2       y3    y4
1  1 10.2 10.2 10.2 8.000000 7.942000 8.81 8.378000 7.472
2  2  8.0  8.0  8.0 9.833333 7.133333 6.41 6.768333 7.525
```

### aggregate

Note that in base R it can be done like this:

```
aggregate(. ~ id, anscombe, mean)
```

giving:

```
  id   x1   x2   x3       x4       y1   y2       y3    y4
1  1 10.2 10.2 10.2 8.000000 7.942000 8.81 8.378000 7.472
2  2  8.0  8.0  8.0 9.833333 7.133333 6.41 6.768333 7.525
```